# Finite number of topological spaces realized by varieties of bounded degree?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

I am not familiar with algebraic geometry so I am sorry if this question is terribly ignorant.  Any basic reference is appreciated.

Is there a finite bound on the number of topological spaces that can occur as the zero locus in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ of a degree $d$ homogeneous polynomial in $n+1$ variables with real coefficients?

What about the analogous question over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I guess so, and a more general statement should hold with the vanishing locus of $\le m$ homogeneous polynomials of  degree $\le d$ in $n+1$ variables.

Comment: If you restrict to smooth ones, then Ehresmann theorem tells you they are all diffeomorphic.

Comment: Using Hilbert Schemes, an equivalent question is whether, given a flat proper family $X\to S$ of schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{R}$, we have finitely many topological types in the fibres. It *may* be easier to answer the question over $\mathbb{C}$ first.

Comment: A colleague (Alok Maharana) points out that Varchenko in Izv. Akad. Nauk. 36(1972)5 has proved that there is a finite stratification of the base of a family for which the fibres are equisingular on each stratum. This should lead to a solution.